# ignore HH:mm:ss from search query

Tags: php, getdate

I have the following php code:

```
$result102=DB::Query("select count(HSEQDepotAuditPk) as total FROM dbo.Audit_HSEQDepotAudits WHERE AuditStatus > 1 AND GETDATE() > AuditEndDate AND ReportProductionDate IS NULL");
```

The idea is that it sits on a scheduled cronjob that is updated at 1am every day, to update the status based on date.

The problem I am having is that it returns results where it is greater OR equal to todays date, and I only want it to produce when greater than.  the database value is yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss, but when i look at database, all the hh:mm:ss are 00:00:00, so I suspect that the GETDATE() is including hh:mm:ss at current time, so 2022-07-10 15:27:00 (NOW) will be greater than 2022-07-10 00:00:00.

How can I modify this search string so that now only includes YYYY-mm-dd, I have tried date(now()) but get the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function value() on bool

Comment: sorry i should have searched a little harder, found my answer : CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()) > CONVERT(DATE,AuditEndDate)

Answer (score 0):

CONVERT(DATE,GETDATE()) > CONVERT(DATE,AuditEndDate)